# Minifed js files and css files are not loading with 403 error in Chrome Developer's tool console

Tags: javascript, wordpress, minify

I was using W3 Total Cache and it was working fine. Suddenly after updating Wordpress I started having issues with JS and CSS loading on the website. I checked Chrome DevTools console and there were these errors "Failed to load resource" for the minified js and css files.
I then installed Autooptimize plugin and now I am getting the same errors:

```
autoptimize_single_5ee990907b315027da600eeeaee2e04b.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Refused to apply style from 'https://site/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/css/autoptimize_8ddffc35874a442e23f067ea66798a49.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting the permissions for all the files and folders inside /wp-content/cache/ to 755 via FTP.